# How to filter a tab-separated data file against a dictionary file for an index column from command-line?

Tags: perl, sed, awk, grep

I have file `file1` containing

```
123 foo
45  bar
678 foobar
...
```

and `file2` containing

```
xyz
foo
foobar
...
```

I'd like to get a file with only rows from `file1` whose second column
appear in `file2`:

```
123 foo
678 foobar
...
```

The columns are separated by tabs.  I'd like to run this from
Mac OS X command-line if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definately a job for `join`:

```
$ join -1 2 -2 1 <(sort file) <(sort file2)
foo 123
foobar 678
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %seen;
open (my $input2, "<", "input2") or die("open input2: $!");
while (<$input2>) { chomp; $seen{$_}++; }
close $input2;

open (my $input1, "<", "input1") or die("open input1: $!");
while (<$input1>) {
  chomp;
  my $key = (split (/\s+/))[1];
  print "$_\n" if $seen{$key};
}
close $input1;
```

Or you can do this using `join` and `sort`:

```
sort input2 > input2sorted
join -1 2 -2 1 input1 input2sorted
```

Also next time you can post your take on the question and ask a more specific question.

Comment: Why it needs `sort` first?

Comment: `join` arguments should be in sorted order

Answer (score 2):

**Try this :**

```
grep -f file2 file1 > Output.txt
```

**file1**

```
123 foo
45  bar
678 foobar
```

**file2**

```
xyz
foo
foobar
```

**Output.txt**

```
123 foo
678 foobar
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk -F "\t" 'FNR==NR { a[$0]++; next } $2 in a' file2 file1
```

Results:

```
123 foo
678 foobar
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}($2 in a)' file2 file1
```

check [here](http://theunixshell.blogspot.in/2012/12/file-comparisons-using-awk-match-columns.html)  or [here](http://theunixshell.blogspot.in/2012/12/awk-one-liner-for-multi-column.html) for more examples:

Answer (score 0):

Here's a perl option that uses [File::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/~uri/File-Slurp-9999.19/lib/File/Slurp.pm) to read your files.  `map` is used to initialize a hash with the 'keys,' and a regex gets the last column entry that's used in `grep` to pass through only matching lines if the entry's in the hash:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp qw/read_file/;

my %keys = map { chomp; $_ => 1 } read_file 'file2.txt';
print for grep { /\t(.+)$/; $keys{$1} } read_file 'file1.txt';
```

Output on your data sets:

```
123 foo
678 foobar
```